# Should [medical] and [medicine] be merged?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

[medical](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medical) has 89 questions as of now and the following short and long descriptions:

> For questions about the diagnosis, treatment, and prevention of disease and injury.

> This tag describes questions that address the diagnosis, treatment, and prevention of disease and injury. The scope of this tag is vast, so it is important to be specific and use additional tags to clarify what you need.
>
> Relevant tags may include [creature-design](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creature-design), [reality-check](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reality-check), and [technology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology)

[medicine](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medicine) has 169 questions right now, with the following descriptions:

> For questions about treatment methods as well as substances used to heal wounds and cure diseases.

> Medicine is a discipline concerned with healing the sick and injured, with alleviating suffering and with promoting physical and mental well-being.
>
> Medicines are substances used to help creatures recuperate from illnesses. They can be injected or taken orally, in the form of solids or liquids.
>
> See also the [disease](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disease) and [epidemiology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/epidemiology) tags.

---

They seem similar enough to each other that they could be turned into one. Should we merge them?

Answer (score 7):

Simple answer: yes.

However, it might make more sense to combine the [medicine](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medicine) and [pharmacology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pharmacology) tags, making one a synonym of the other.

I do see a difference between pharmacology and medical procedure.

Comment: Concur. A three step process would solve the issue: 1 --- sift through the MEDICINE questions and retag those that relate to drugs, pharmacology, healing substances, potions, elixirs to PHARMACOLOGY; 2 --- sift through whatever's left and retag the medical procedure queries MEDICAL; 3 --- whatever's left from those two processes, retag (or detag) as appropriate & erase the MEDICINE tag.

Comment: Yes.  Split "medicine" because it's ambiguous.